# Change Listview row color in Elementary nautilus?

Tags: nautilus-elementary

How to style the rows color in Elementary Nautilus (list view)?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!